# Iterate through a JSON Object with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How would I iterate through the following JSON object with two or more nested arrays?  The output here isn't being returned with key:value.  It's just the values.

```
{"Obj":
    ["array 0",
        ["nested array 1"],
        ["nested array 2"]
    ]
};
```

I can view each array using `Obj[1]` but the output remains in JSON: `{"Obj":["nested array 1"]}`.  I need to iterate through all of them to obtain the text in each nested array to put into a textarea...

Help!

Thanks all!

Comment: Try with a `while` loop, or recursion. Or flatten the nested array.

Comment: How do you flatten the nested array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to iterate through the arrays at each level. On the first level you can use `$.type()` to determine the type of the value so as to help decide whether to output the value or to further iterate it.

```
var data = {"Obj":
    ["array 0",
        ["nested array 1"],
        ["nested array 2"]
    ]
};

$.each( data.Obj, function(i,v) {
    if( $.type( v ) == 'string' ) {
        // assign v to text
    } else {
        $.each( v, function(index, value) {
            //assign value to text
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-jQuery solution, try `Obj[i][j]`. The following code outputs "nested array 1" followed by "nested array 2" to the console.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Obj.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Obj[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(Obj[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I was able to get your solution to work.  Thank you!  How would I handle automatically looping through results with more dimensions?

Comment: As in you don't know the number of dimensions and you need to dynamically determine how many dimensions there are?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to loop through an object or array is to use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a
>   length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated
>   by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via
>   their named properties.

Example:

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

If you have an unknown number of nested arrays, you'll probably want to create a recursive function that calls itself with nested values.